# How to see if a coax cable is able to receive Internet?

Tags: coaxial-cable, internet

During construction works every cable in the house was cut off.
The cable was only used for TV so far, but we want now also receive Internet by cable.
Now we have a lose coax-cable (presumably from our local provider) out of the wall.

The question is: can we receive not only TV and Radio, but also Internet using this cable?

A companioned electrician meant that the cable had to be trinominal which confused me.
What did he mean by that?

The cable is an Kathrein LCD 90

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, there's no way we can figure out your wiring problems from here. You need someone on site who can figure out how to get a signal from your ISP into your house. (Sorry.)

Comment: @DanielGriscom It's not about "am I receiving the signal" or "how to get the cable into my house". The cable IS already in the house. The question is, if the cable is the correct one to be able to receive internet.

Comment: You don't buy a reel of cable and put it in your house and bingo: you have "cable". It's a whole system, and again: there's no way we can figure this out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply call your cable provider to come hook you up to internet. If need be, they will replace the cable, otherwise they will simply terminate it.

Your "companioned electrician" is misinformed, as are you. You don't need triax or biax for getting internet from the cable TV folks, even though there are other systems which use such cables, mostly hoary antiquities at this point in time. A coaxial cable has two conductors - they are, not surprisingly, coaxial - a center conductor, and a shield, which is also a conductor. Which makes two conductors, not one.

Regardless, just call your cable internet, TV, etc. provider and ask them to hook you up. The vast majority of CableTV internet comes in on exactly the same cable as the TV does, though if the cable is in poor condition due to age or abuse they may choose to replace it anyway. They have specialized test devices the installer will use to check the signal levels at the cable and determine if it will work. Since those are specific to the cable system and typically have a pricetag near that of a car, it's not a DIY project, it's a part of their service provision.

Answer (score 1):

It either works or it doesn't.   You could run some gaming system that has a coax output to test or something like that - but that just tells you if your line isn't cut, not that it works for the cable/internet provider.

I suggest you order internet service and tell the company that this is reliant on that they make their service work with current cabling.   The technician will 9 times out of 10 try to get your cabling to work and might even troubleshoot for you.

If you tell them that you might have cable issues and are vague, they will just discard your current cables and run new ones which could either look bad or be rather intrusive.